# Computer freezes on heavy disk usage

Tags: windows, freeze

I have this problem that my PC freezes (for a short period) when disk usage goes high. This happens during games (at worst possible moments) and when uTorrent starts download. I have fast SSD and speed test shows above 500MB/s disk read/write speeds. However - computer freeze is not something I would expect as normal PC behavior. I only have 8GB of ram so I think, that heavy disk usage during gameplay could be associated with swap file (Windows 10) however - even if so - it seems that there is some driver problem... How do I verify / reproduce this problem and fix it? My laptop is Dell M7510 and I expect no freezing from it.

Answer (score 1):

Freezing while doing disk IO is normal - it's less of an issue with SSDs but disk IO is still a blocking process.

You might want to look at your disk utilization, fragmentation and SSD firmware as all of these things can impact on your drive (yes, SSDs do suffer the effects of fragmentation - sequential reads are faster then random ones.)

Comment: Part of why I am asking this question is because I remember old days, when "going to die" hdd would fall back to dma 0 (or whatever slow mode) in windows and similar issues would pop-out. Back then going to device manager and changing disk access mode would fix the issue, but there is no such tab for disk devices anymore.. :/

Comment: Those days are long gone and this does not apply to the technology.